# Is it possible to make a copy of object in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

Being aware of 'Copy List' keyword, I did little experiment:

```
${a}=  Create List  3  5
${b}=  set variable  ${a}
append to list  ${b}  6
log to console  ${a}
log to console  ${b}

[u'3', u'5', u'6']
[u'3', u'5', u'6']
```

So basically, 'set variable' simply makes a reference to 'a'
In case of lists and dicts, robot has possiblity to make copy, but what about other objects? Is it possible to make copy, not reference to an object in RF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deep copy for collection is available from robotframework==3.1.2

```
${a}=  Create List  3  5
${b}=  Copy List  ${a}  deepcopy=True
append to list  ${b}  6
log to console  ${a}
log to console  ${b}

[u'3', u'5']
[u'3', u'5', u'6']
```

If its non collection object you can use python `copy.deepcopy(obj)`