# How to properly use 'Copy List' in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have searched the documentation and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527385/is-it-possible-to-make-a-copy-of-object-in-robot-framework) question but still no luck on my side.
I just want to use the 'Copy List' keyword.

```
 *** Settings ***
    Documentation       Example of working with Lists
    Variables           variables.py
    Library             SeleniumLibrary
    Library             Collections

*** Variables ***

*** Test Cases ***
[TC01] Copy List Example
   @{list1} =  create list     item1    item2    item3    item4
   @{clist1} = copy list       ${list1}

*** Keywords ***
```

I get an error:

```
No keyword with name '@{clist1} = copy list' found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file format is wrong. Read this section "[Space separated format](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#space-separated-format)" and figure it out.

Correct space separated format:

```
@{clist1}=    Copy List    ${list1}
```